# In the console of eclipse, how can I print several things one next to other?

Tags: java, eclipse

well, that's the general idea. Having this:

```java
Arbol A: 
*3
   +2
      +-3
         +5)
         +-3)
      +8)
   +-1
      +4)
      +-2
         +0)
         +1)

Resultado: 
*14
   +9
      +-1
         +5)
         +-3)
      +8)
   +2
      +4)
      +-1
         +0)
         +1)
```

I want the displayed result being like this:

```java
Arbol A:                           Resultado: 
*3                                 *14
   +2                                 +9
      +-3                                +-1      
         +5)                                +5)
         +-3)                               +-3)
      +8)                                +8)
   +-1                                +2                       
      +4)                                +4)
      +-2                                +-1
         +0)                               +0)
         +1)                               +1)
```

This is only an example, the idea is to display anything without seeing the results one under other. Maybe It's useful but, both "Arbol A" and "resultado" are independent methods.

Any idea? I didn't find anything.

Comment: Can you edit the two "independent methods"?

Comment: There's nothing from the JDK that will do this, and I have never heard of this kind of thing even being talked about, let alone done. Also, please don't post images of output; edit your question and put the sample content in your question as plain text formatted as code (ie indent with 4 spaces)

Comment: @Sweeper yeah, those are to different methods. I've used some binary trees as example because It is what I am studying right now.

Comment: @Bohemian corrections done. Thanks!

Comment: @daenius I was asking whether you intend to **edit** the two methods (see my answer for why you need to do this). So I guess it's a yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have no other output going to STDOUT, you can hijack `System.out`, capture the output while other methods run, return `System.out` to its normal state, then re-format the captured output and print it.

```
PrintStream original = System.out;
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4096);
PrintStream tempPrinter = new PrintStream(buffer);
System.setOut(tempPrinter);

// call methods that print

tempPrinter.flush();
System.setOut(original);

String output = buffer.toString(); // contains all output, including new lines
```

I leave it to you to format and output to your desired format.
You may find `for (String line : output.split("\\R"))` and `line.endsWith(":")` useful in this endeavour.

Answer (score 0):

Try using \t (tabulator) in the String and then just put the values and text elements in the right places in the String, \t works similar to putting a space between elements only that it's way bigger and should make it look like result 2

Comment: It didn't help me, but I found out the utility of the tabulator \t. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to print to the console like that. You must print line by line. What you can do though, is to take 2 strings, cut them up, and arrange them in columns, producing a string that looks like it has 2 columns. You can then print *this* string.

This means that you must edit the methods that prints the output so that they don't print the output, but return their output as a string. For example, a method such as this:

```
public static void print1To10() {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
public static String get1To10String() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
        sb.append(i);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Now you can write the method that takes 2 strings and arrange them in columns. Here's one that I have written. It *is* slow and it can be improved (haven't tested for edge cases either), but I'm not going to, because this is just a very rough implementation, meant to give you an idea of what needs to be done.

```
// separation is an extra parameter I decide to add in to let the caller specify the distance between the columns.
public static String putSideBySide(String left, String right, int separation) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String[] leftLines = left.split(System.lineSeparator());
    String[] rightLines = right.split(System.lineSeparator());
    int maxLeftLength = Arrays.stream(leftLines).mapToInt(String::length).max().orElse(0);
    int minLines = Math.min(leftLines.length, rightLines.length);

    // for the rows where both the left and right have stuff
    for (int i = 0 ; i < minLines ; i++) {
        sb.append(leftLines[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < maxLeftLength - leftLines[i].length() + separation; j++) {
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        sb.append(rightLines[i]);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    if (leftLines.length < rightLines.length) {
        // only the right columns
        for (int i = 0 ; i < rightLines.length - leftLines.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < maxLeftLength + separation ; j++) {
                sb.append(' ');
            }
            sb.append(rightLines[i + leftLines.length]);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    } else {
        // only the left columns
        for (int i = 0 ; i < leftLines.length - rightLines.length ; i++) {
            sb.append(leftLines[i + rightLines.length]);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(putSideBySide(func1(), func2(), 4));
}

public static String func1() {
    return "Hello World,\n" +
            "This is some sample text.\n" +
            "Testing Testing Testing\n" +
            "Lorem Ipsum";
}

public static String func2() {
    return "This is the right column,\n" +
            "which is on the right of the left column.\n" +
            "This column\n" +
            "has\n" +
            "more\n" +
            "rows.";
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World,                 This is the right column,
This is some sample text.    which is on the right of the left column.
Testing Testing Testing      This column
Lorem Ipsum                  has
                             more
                             rows.
```

Comment: Many thanks, though It didn't help entirely, It gave me an idea of what I would do. The two methods that I mentioned above return each one a BinaryTree, BUT, formated like you see (the root is marked with an asterisk for example). So, that formatter method returns a String. With this info and with what you taught me, I will do a method, that taking to BinaryTrees returns the one desired (I am thinking to, at the same time I am going down the tree by each level, I will print each two trees). I hope you get my idea. Thanks again!

Comment: @daenius I think you are quite close to the solution actually. Can't you just pass the string returned by your formatter method to `putSideBySide`?

Comment: Using your method and your advice of using both yours and mine the thing just doesn't work. For example "This is the right column" appears at the third line, next to "Lorem Ipsum".  But don't worry, I will try what I told you. If It is a success I will link it here or something hehe